# Click Once update version duplication problem

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a come across a weird problem with apps deployed using Click-Once. For example, the app called 'MyApplication' appears in the start menu as 'MyApplication' after the initial deployment. After a couple of updates a new version 'MyApplication - 1' is created in the start menu, n sometimes it goes to version ' - 2' and ' - 3' and all..And all these versions co-exist very peacefully without disturbing each other at all!!! And I can uninstall any of these version from control panel without affecting the other. And I have tried this from both VS2005 apps n VS2010 apps.

While getting my app ready for an update,the publish version is changed regularly (as that happens by default) and I change the Assembly version sometimes if the code change is major. Other than that I dont change any of the default settings.I have tried to re-create this error by changing assembly version and code changes , but it was never able to re-create the error in the test environment. But it still occurs now and then with my live applications.

Was wondering if anyone else have come across a similar issue. Will be so gratefull if anyone can suggest a solution for this. It has been bothering me for so long now.

Many Thanks,
Mary

Comment: Does the machine have different users that login?  Could it be possible that more then one user installed the app?

Comment: Also when are you doing the updates?

Comment: Hi Tony, The app is installed only on a single profile on a PC usually and The updates are run as and when any new features is to be released, once or twice a month probably.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same situation. This happens when you modify assembly name, in this case it treats the clickonce application as the new application hence multiple instances of same application with different names. If you want to check whether this is the same situation you faced, check the installation folder in client machine, you will have multiple instances of your application with different folder.